# using KeyWord + Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, using

I found some strange Code in a old project of us, which is looking like this:

```
using (var removeGroupMembershipWorker = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    removeGroupMembershipWorker.DoWork += (senderRGMW, eRGMW) =>
    {

    };
    removeGroupMembershipWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The Code in the Lambda is elided.

For me, the `using` Keyword and the lambda expression don't go well together: The Lambda has to leverage the object on a Class-Level, otherwise the code could not be called later.

But how does the `using` Keyword work here? The Thread obviously doesn't wait for the Async to finish, but what happens when the `using` block is left?

Is the `using` just ignored in such cases?

Edith says: Since I'm missing Raghus answer and this superb link; I add it here: http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2011/12/09/Using-blocks-and-asynchronous-operations.aspx
This explains the problematic and the solution about the Topic.

Comment: Can you post body of RunWorkerAsync() method?

Comment: No need thanks, as Raghu wrote, these 2 concepts dont work well together

Comment: There is no problem with the interaction between `using` and lambdas, the problem here is that the object is supposed to live longer due to being asynchronous. So the lambda isn't the problem here, the async nature + dispose is.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` block is syntactic sugar for a `try` ... `finally` construct in which the `finally` block calls the `IDisposable.Dispose()` method of the object.  This is, of course, why the object being disposed must implement `IDisposable`, else you get a compile-time error.

Calling `Dispose()` is not the same as allowing the object to go out of scope to be garbage-collected.  In particular, if code within the lambda happens to refer to `removeGroupMembershipWorker` by closure, the lambda could end up referring to an object that has been disposed.  This scenario may or may not cause errors, depending what `Dispose()` actually does.

So, as you mention, the `using` pattern may not be the best idea here.  If you do need to call `Dispose()` -- which you really should for any `IDisposable` -- you can call it directly when it would be safe to do so.  What "safe to do so" means depends on your code, but in essence, `Dispose()` needs to be the last method called on the object (except any methods called within `Dispose()`, of course).

Comment: Saying which is the last call is generally not possible I'd say, since we dont know in which order the async Methods get worked on.
As said, I think there are really really few objects which are IDisposable and have async Methods, Backgroundworker the only one I know so far.

Strangely, I'm missing a Comment by Raghu, which had a very good Link about this topic.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller, you would not want to call `Dispose()` until after all async operations have completed, which is why `using` probably won't work well here.  There are a variety of ways to determine when the object should actually be disposed, but without more information, I would not know what to suggest.

Comment: Streams have asynchronous methods as well.